# How to get first and last name separately with Github Oauth (using Passport.js)?

Tags: oauth, github-api

How can one request the first and last names separately from the Github OAuth API?

I've looked at the [scopes in the docs](https://developer.github.com/apps/building-oauth-apps/understanding-scopes-for-oauth-apps/) and even with `read:user`, the response only includes `displayName`, which concatenates (with spaces) the first and last name of the user. But [separating them via `split`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/97696/function-to-split-full-name-into-first-last) carries with it many problems.

Does Github OAuth support providing firstName and lastName fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Name` field is a free-form input for the user, so they can put whatever they would like in there. There are plenty of [myths about names that programmers should be aware of](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/), so I'd advise being relaxed about what your application can handle here.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Didn't realize Github only collected a single name field.